# A better way to submit a form for Django

Tags: django, django-forms

This is what I am doing at the moment:

views.py

```
def activation_signupcount(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        return render_to_response('activation_signupcount.html', 
                                {   'datestart': request.POST['datestart'], 
                                    'dateend': request.POST['dateend'], 
                                    'usersegment': request.POST['usersegment'], 
                                    'segment_form': SegmentForm(request.POST), 
                                    'date_form': DateSelectForm(request.POST)    })
    else:

        return render_to_response('activation_signupcount.html', 
                                {'segment_form': SegmentForm(), 'date_form': DateSelectForm()})
```

template

```
{% extends "base_activation.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>Sign ups</h2>
    <p>Number of users who have registered to the site between the dates entered</p>
{% endblock %}

{% block graph %}
    {% if datestart %}
    <p>This counts the number of <strong>{{ usersegment }}</strong> users who have successfully registered to the site (verified their email)
    who joined between <strong>{{ datestart }}</strong> and <strong>{{ dateend }}</strong></p>
    <img src="./activation_signupcount.png?usersegment={{ usersegment }}&datestart={{ datestart }}&dateend={{ dateend }}" />
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

So I am returning the same page when a user submits the SegmentForm and DateSelectForms. To check if I should return the output (a graph), I am checking for the existence of `datestart` as seen in my template `{% if datestart %}` if it was submitted.

Is this a Djangoic way of doing it? I feel I ought to be checking for `response == 'POST'` rather than forcing the check variable to `datestart`.

Thanks

Comment: Most of the examples and tutorials on the website do the same thing, so I guess it is 'Djangonic'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a few pointers to save you headaches when debugging the code. Instead of testing for request.method == 'POST', check whether the value you have attached to the submit button on your form(s) (in the template) is in the request.POST dictionary. I'm not sure whether you are submitting 2 forms with one "submit"-button, but if you do, why not write one form for it?

Also, always check whether your form is valid. This saves you a lot of headaches when rendering your graph, as the code for the graph can then safely make certain assumptions about the quality of the data it receives. Also, the user will know why the graph doesn't render (he'll get error messages in his form).

You could make the validation check in the template or in the view (the latter is recommended - program logic should reside in your views). If your forms are valid, they will get the "cleaned_data" properties, containing the validated data.

Off the top of my head, here's what more Django-ic code would look like:

```
def render_view(request):
    if "submit" in request.POST: # Supposing both forms are submitted with one "submit" button
        segment_form = SegmentForm(request.POST)
        dateselect_form = DateSelectForm(request.POST)
    else:
        segment_form = SegmentForm()
        dateselect_form = DateSelectForm()

    return render_to_response('activation_signupcount.html',{'segment_form': segment_form, 'date_form': date_form, 'display_graph': (segment_form.is_valid() and dateselect_form.is_valid())})
```

Then, in your template, first check if the forms are valid (the 'display_graph' variable is True if both forms are valid), and then access their cleaned_data properties to get the values you want. For instance:

```
{% block graph %}
{% if display_graph %}
    <p>This counts the number of <strong>{{ segment_form.cleaned_data.usersegment }}</strong> users who have successfully registered to the site (verified their email)who joined between <strong>{{ date_form.cleaned_data.datestart }}</strong> and <strong>{{ date_form.cleaned_data.dateend }}</strong></p>
<img src="./activation_signupcount.png?usersegment={{ segment_form.cleaned_data.usersegment }}&datestart={{ date_form.cleaned_data.datestart }}&dateend={{ date_form.cleaned_data.dateend  }}" />
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: The validation check in the code I gave you is at the end, in the return statement, where one of the dict keys is 'display_graph': (segment_form.is_valid() and dateselect_form.is_valid()). This will set display_graph to True if the forms are valid.

Comment: Question: Why check for `submit` instead of `request == 'POST'`?

Comment: It might be unnecessary in this case, but it's good practice. This way, you are sure that the code after your if... statement pertains to the form you want to check. In other words, if you would get a request POSTed to the same view, and the POST comes from another form or source than the form you want to check, the code isn't executed.

Answer (score 2):

That's the most strange way to submit a form I've ever seen. :-) First of all, you pass `segment_form` and `date_form` to your template but don't use them at all. Why? Second, you have no validation, what if `datestart` will be 'adhbsadfbsrbv'? Or some XSS statement? Third, what if there will be no `datestart` in POST at all? You will get `KeyError`.

May be you should read [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) first. Your code can be rewritten somehow like this (even simplier edited version):

```
def activation_signupcount(request):
    return render_to_response('activation_signupcount.html',
                          {'segment_form': SegmentForm(request.POST or None), 'date_form': DateSelectForm(request.POST or None)})
```

And in template you can access the variables like `{{ date_form.cleaned_data.datestart }}` And don't forget to use `escape` filter when outputting urls.

Comment: Heh, you beat me to it :) (Btw, I presume the "base_activation.html" template uses the forms).